MRI related forum
my question is about what forum discusses the MRI sequence effects on images. Is this the right forum to ask question about MRI sequences and sequence comparisons?
E.g., currently focused on spair sequence and can we use se t2wi in place of it. why use a sequence particularly?

This question seems more appropriate for the Medical Science SE or Biology SE. You might find more relevant and qualified people there.

TYVM THE QUESTION MAY BE DELETED
